# Select Box to change value in PHP of a API URL with JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

How can I use AJAX to update an API URL from a value in a select box?

This is where I am at. User selects a date period from a select box to change analytic dates

```
<select name="DateSelector" id="DateSelector" onchange="return datePeriod();">
  <option selected value="30">Last 30 Days</option>
  <option value="90">Last 90 Days</option>
  <option value="365">Last 365 Days</option>
</select>
```

and using JS, I get the value from `onchange`

```
function datePeriod() {
  var x = document.getElementById("DateSelector").value;
  document.getElementById("DateShow").innerHTML = x;
}
```

And want to use this value in PHP to change the value of the `date=last` of the API.

```
$DatePeriod = '$_GET["DateShow"]';
$url = "https://example.com";
$url .= "?module=API&method=API.get&format=php";
$url .= "&idSite=2&period=day&date=last$DatePeriod";
```

With these snippets, I seem to be falling short. Could someone point me in the right direction? Just to reiterate, I want a user to be able to select a date range (default of `30` days as `value`) and update the API URL.

Please also keep in mind that I am needing to update the values of the analytics from the new API URL as a user changes the select value.

**UPDATE:**
Considering that the above code is changing the value of the API URL, then how can I ensure that upon a user selecting a value these elements are updated?

```
$nb_visits           = 0;
$nb_uniq_visitors   = 0;
$nb_pageviews       = 0;
$nb_uniq_pageviews  = 0;
$nb_actions         = 0;
$nb_outlinks        = 0;
$bounce_count       = 0;
$avg_time_on_site   = 0;
```

So that `<?php echo $data['nb_visits']; ?>` for example (in page template, not function) is updated as a user changes the select value?

**FULL PHP FUNCTION**

```
$DatePeriod = '$_GET["DateShow"]';
$token_auth = 'API_TOKEN';
$url = "https://example.com/";
$url .= "?module=API&method=API.get&format=php";
$url .= "&idSite=2&period=day&date=last$DatePeriod";
$url .= "&token_auth=$token_auth";

$fetched = file_get_contents($url);
$content = unserialize($fetched);

// case error
if (!$content) {
    print("NO DATA");
}
$nb_visits          = 0;
$nb_uniq_visitors   = 0;
$nb_pageviews       = 0;
$nb_uniq_pageviews  = 0;
$nb_actions         = 0;
$nb_outlinks        = 0;
$bounce_count       = 0;
$avg_time_on_site   = 0;

foreach ($content as $row) {
    $nb_visits          += $row['nb_visits'];
    $nb_uniq_visitors   += $row['nb_uniq_visitors'];
    $nb_pageviews       += $row['nb_pageviews'];
    $nb_uniq_pageviews  += $row['nb_uniq_pageviews'];
    $nb_actions         += $row['nb_actions'];
    $nb_outlinks        += $row['nb_outlinks'];
    $bounce_count       += $row['bounce_count'];
    $avg_time_on_site   += $row['avg_time_on_site'];
}

$data = [
    'nb_visits'         => $nb_visits,
    'nb_uniq_visitors'  => $nb_uniq_visitors,
    'nb_pageviews'      => $nb_pageviews,
    'nb_uniq_pageviews' => $nb_uniq_pageviews,
    'nb_actions'        => $nb_actions,
    'nb_outlinks'       => $nb_outlinks,
    'bounce_count'      => $bounce_count,
    'avg_time_on_site'  => $avg_time_on_site,
];
```

Comment: You tagged this as AJAX, have you tried anything using JS so far?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Only what is above. I had tagged with AJAX as I foresee that being the best way to achieve the update in realtime. At this moment I am still trying to figure out whether my above code is working at all.

Comment: Well, the code you showed us doesnt really do anything, so, yeah, it works just fine

Comment: I have added more information to my question. Hopefully, this gives understanding to where I intended AJAX to be needed. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: How are you using PHP here? Is this code on the same page as the JS and HTML?

Comment: Calling the API and the output of API data is via my functions.php, JS is external and the values are `echo` from the output data into page template using `<?php echo $data['nb_visits']; ?>`

Comment: So this is an entirely different file?

Comment: Yes, but that is easily changed if this is not possible in doing via multiple files.

Comment: You don't actually need PHP... Is this all you do in your PHP file?

Comment: Any suggestions as answers would be greatly appreciated. I was just thinking of adding the full URLs to each select value and using AJAX to update the `$url` in my function. Still not sure if this would work for updating the output from PHP though.

Comment: I am working on an answer right now :)

Comment: Took a little longer than I expected (was watching tv)... Don't be afraid to ask if you don't understand something

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162672/discussion-between-darren-and-luca).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you tagged this as `jquery` I am assuming you already have that in your HTML.

If you look at the Piwik URL, you can see that one get parameter changes the output format (`...&format=php&i...`), with this you can easily eliminate all PHP for this by changing it to (`...&format=json&i...`)

In your JS `datePeriod()` function you can get the desired data if you call the API using AJAX:

```
function datePeriod() {
  let datePeriod = $("#DateSelector").val();
  $("#DateShow").html(datePeriod);
  $.getJSON(`https://domain/?module=API&method=API.get&format=json&idSite=2&period=day&date=last${datePeriod}&token_auth=68...`, data => {
    let visits;
    for(i in data) { 
      let a = data[i].nb_visits; 
      if(a) { // this makes sure that we don't add undefined to our number
        visits+=a
      }
    }
    $("#whereYouWantToDisplayYourHits").html(visits);
  }

}
```

You can of course expand this to show all kinds of stuff, like for example your unique pageviews:

```
function datePeriod() {
  let datePeriod = $("#DateSelector").val();
  $("#DateShow").html(datePeriod);
  $.getJSON(`https://domain/?module=API&method=API.get&format=json&idSite=2&period=day&date=last${datePeriod}&token_auth=68...`, data => {
    let visits;
    let uniquePageviews;
    for(i in data) { 
      let a = data[i].nb_visits; 
      if(a) { // this makes sure that we don't add undefined to our number
        visits+=a;
      }
      let b = data[i].nb_uniq_pageviews;
      if (b) {uniquePageviews+=b;}
    }
    $("#whereYouWantToDisplayYourHits").html(visits);
    $("#whereYouWantToDisplayYourUNi...").html(uniquePageviews);
    // and so on
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, don't see any issues but give me a few minutes to check this and I'll get back to you.

Comment: One thing to add is, that you'll now have that API token in the public. If users only get to see this that would have access to that API either way, this makes no difference, but if you don't want someone to see e.g. the avg_site_on_time, you would be better off having PHP as a wrapper for this

Comment: Okay, I had to make a few changes due to errors but does not seem to pull the JSON. Would you mind if I start a chat and walk you through what I am doing?

Comment: Understand. Thank you very much for your time. I'll figure it out and let you know. Cheers again.